# Wordpress subdomain and multiple sites

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, multiple-databases

I have a wordpress website say www. flowers.com .
Now can i have 3 subdomain called "Roses" , "sunflower" , "orchids" with a fresh wp install eg: www. roses.flower.com  , and main website got links pointing each sub dir index file. And they all working fine

Now how do one user log in all sites with one user name  ?

I tried using same sql directory database on all subdomain sites, but still each and every time the user need to login  for different subdomains .

all ideas are welcome .

thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Wordpress Multisite installation using Subdomains](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Comment: But, the themes can be only one for all sites ? especially the main theme and child themes.no ? 0_o

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wordpress "multisite" feature and then link each individual blog to a subdomain.

More about multisite: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, The multi site option is good but it will be in folders after the domain name rather than sub domains which are before the domain name.

Comment: The multi site option allow to install on sub-domain also, when you setup network there are option for installation in sub-domain or sub-folder.  so, choose sub-domain.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

Our goal is to set up two WordPress websites which will share logins and the same users. Once a user has subscribed one website, she would be able to access the other website with the same role and capabilities.

**Step 1:** In order to share the same users and usermeta tables, WordPress installations must share the same database.

Add prefix of first wordpress installation first_ and second wordpress installation table second_. in same database.

**Step 2:** When the first WordPress website is up and running, we can edit its configuration file. Open /first/wp-config.php and add the following lines above the ‘stop editing’ comment:

```
 $table_prefix  = 'first_';
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
    @ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

// custom users and usermeta tables
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', $table_prefix . 'users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', $table_prefix . 'usermeta' );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

**Step 3:** We are done with the first installation. Next we have to copy wp-config.php from the first installation folder and paste it into the root folder of the second installation. Be careful to change the $table_prefix value accordingly:

open /second/wp-config.php.and add the following lines above the ‘stop editing’ comment:

```
$table_prefix  = 'second_';

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

// custom users and usermeta tables
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'first_users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'first_usermeta' );
```

**Step 4:** write in both wp-config.php for sharing cookies.

```
//Share cookies
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.xyz.com');
define('COOKIEHASH', 'aee53c017c29dc0d3ae37253fc8cbfd8');
```

**Step 5:** Open table "first_usermeta" and copy from column meta_key - first_capabilities and first_user_level to the second_capabilities and second_user_level. 
[image]

**Step 6:** When running the second installation, we should set a non-existent email address for admin user as WordPress finds a number of existing users from first_users table.

For more detail : https://kinsta.com/blog/share-logins-wordpress/.
It's Work For Me.